# How to calculate font size of TextBlock to fill in Canvas?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

What I need is some **formula** to calculate **font size** of `TextBlock` for its owner -  `Canvas`.

Let's say I have `Canvas` height 100.0 then which **`TextBlock` font size** should be to fill all space of the `Canvas`?

*P.S. The main problem is that I scroll those TextBlocks horizontally...*

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to stick the TextBlock in a Viewbox and have that fill the canvas area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution which works fine for me.

```
double h = canvas1.Height / 2; 

 foreach (var item in textBlocks)
 {
    if (item is TextBlock)
    {
         (item as TextBlock).FontSize = h;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use whatever `FontSize` while putting the `TextBlock` in a [`Viewbox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox.aspx) whose `Height` is bound to that of the `Canvas`? (When not set explicitly the `ActualHeight` of the `Canvas`)

Comment: Could you provide some XAML please?

Comment: @DmitryBoyko: No, it's trivial, try for yourself first.

Comment: I am afraid I cannot use this approach... Because I have a lot of TextBlocks. And they scroll horizontally.

Comment: @DmitryBoyko: You could apply one Viewbox per TextBlock, that might be a bit too inconvenient of course...

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution which works fine for me.

```
double h = canvas1.Height / 2; 
TextBlock1.FontSize = h;
```